Source Generator won't see dependent project's classes
I have a Modular Monolith along with Clean Architecture as follows:

Application projects depends on Domain projects, and endpoints are in Application projects while Entities are in Domain projects. Delete endpoints are almost identical, so I wanted to create delete endpoints with source generation. Here is the problem:
Entity definition/abstraction is in Common.Domain project:
public abstract class AuditableEntity : IAuditableEntity
{
....
}

And all modules' Domain projects are depends on this Common.Domain and all Entities are derived from Common.Domain.Entities.AuditableEntity. An example entity inside Inventory module is:
public class Product : AggregateRoot<ProductId> // AggregateRoot is derived from AuditableEntity so Product is an AuditableEntity
{
....
}

So my DeleteEndpointSourceGenerator is able to find entities derived from AuditableEntity if it runs on Domain projects, but can not find any of them if it runs on Application projects(as I need it). How can I solve this?
Here is the DeleteEndpointSourceGenerator:
[Generator]
public class DeleteEndpointSourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    private const string AuditableEntityFullName = "Common.Domain.Entities.AuditableEntity";

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new SyntaxReceiver());
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.SyntaxReceiver is not SyntaxReceiver receiver)
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(_noSyntaxReceiverDescriptor, Location.None));
            return;
        }

        var compilation = context.Compilation;

        var auditableEntitySymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(AuditableEntityFullName);
        if (auditableEntitySymbol == null)
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(_auditableEntityNotFoundDescriptor, Location.None));
            return;
        }

        foreach (var classDeclaration in receiver.CandidateClasses)
        {
            var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(classDeclaration.SyntaxTree);

            if (model.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration) is not INamedTypeSymbol classSymbol)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (!IsDerivedFrom(classSymbol, auditableEntitySymbol))
            {
                continue;
            }

            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(_classInheritsDescriptor, Location.None, classSymbol.Name, auditableEntitySymbol.Name));

            var namespaceName = classSymbol.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString();
            var className = classSymbol.Name;

            var source = GenerateDeleteEndpointCode(namespaceName, className);
            context.AddSource($"{className}_DeleteEndpoint.g.cs", SourceText.From(source, Encoding.UTF8));
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(_endpointGeneratedDescriptor, Location.None, className));
        }
    }

    private static bool IsDerivedFrom(INamedTypeSymbol? classSymbol, INamedTypeSymbol baseTypeSymbol)
    {
        var currentType = classSymbol;
        while (currentType != null)
        {
            if (SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(currentType, baseTypeSymbol))
            {
                return true;
            }
            currentType = currentType.BaseType;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static string GenerateDeleteEndpointCode(string namespaceName, string className)
    {
        var pluralClassName = Pluralize(className);
        return $@"
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Common.Domain.ResultMonad;
using Common.Application.Auth;
using Common.Application.Extensions;
using Common.Application.Persistence;
using {namespaceName};
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Common.Application.ModelBinders;
using Ardalis.Specification;

namespace SourceGenerated.Application.{pluralClassName}.v1.Delete;

internal static class {className}DeleteEndpoint
{{
    internal static void MapEndpoint(RouteGroupBuilder apiGroup)
    {{
        apiGroup
            .MapDelete(""{{id}}"", Delete{className}Async)
            .WithDescription(""Delete a {className}."")
            .MustHavePermission(CustomActions.Delete, CustomResources.{pluralClassName})
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)
            .TransformResultToNoContentResponse();
    }}

    private sealed class {className}ByIdSpec : SingleResultSpecification<{className}>
    {{
        public {className}ByIdSpec({className}Id id)
            => Query
                .Where(p => p.Id == id);
    }}

    private static async Task<Result> Delete{className}Async(
        [FromRoute, ModelBinder(typeof(StronglyTypedIdBinder<{className}Id>))] {className}Id id,
        [FromServices] IRepository<{className}> repository,
        [FromKeyedServices(nameof(Inventory))] IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await repository
            .SingleOrDefaultAsResultAsync(new {className}ByIdSpec(id), cancellationToken)
            .TapAsync(entity => repository.Delete(entity))
            .TapAsync(async _ => await unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken));
}}
";
    }

    private static string Pluralize(string word)
    {
        if (word.EndsWith("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return $"{word.Substring(0, word.Length - 1)}ies";
        }

        if (word.EndsWith("s", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return $"{word}es";
        }

        return $"{word}s";
    }

    private sealed class SyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
    {
        public List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> CandidateClasses { get; } = [];

        public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
        {
            if (syntaxNode is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclarationSyntax)
            {
                CandidateClasses.Add(classDeclarationSyntax);
            }
        }
    }

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor _noSyntaxReceiverDescriptor = new(
        id: "GEN001",
        title: "Syntax Receiver Not Found",
        messageFormat: "Syntax receiver not found",
        category: "SourceGenerator",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor _auditableEntityNotFoundDescriptor = new(
        id: "GEN002",
        title: "AuditableEntity Not Found",
        messageFormat: "AuditableEntity not found",
        category: "SourceGenerator",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor _endpointGeneratedDescriptor = new(
        id: "GEN003",
        title: "Endpoint Generated",
        messageFormat: "Generated delete endpoint for {0}",
        category: "SourceGenerator",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Info,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor _classInheritsDescriptor = new(
        id: "GEN004",
        title: "Class Inherits AuditableEntity",
        messageFormat: "{0} is derived from {1}",
        category: "SourceGenerator",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Info,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);
}


Expected behaviour is:

Let's say we run this source generator on Inventory.Application project, it should find the Inventory.Domain entities (Inventory.Application has a reference to Inventory.Domain) then generate this endpoint. But it can't. It only finds Inventory.Domain entities if it runs on Inventory.Domain.


According to your scenario and description it seems the compilation context not including necessary references when running in the Application project.  Please check,  that all necessary metadata references are added to the compilation context, and verify that the Application project correctly references the Domain project. Additionally, adding diagnostic logging to the generator can help identify what references are included and what types are available, aiding in debugging the visibility of the entities.

While running the generator see sources belonging to assembly that is being built. So it's normal that it cannot see anything outside.
To inspect other, referenced assembly use the collection of referenced assembly symbols accessible by:
IAssemblySymbol assemblySymbol = context.Compilation
    .SourceModule
    .ReferencedAssemblySymbols
    .First(q => q.Name == "Inventory.Domain");

There you will find AuditableEntities from "Inventory.Domain".
You can iterate over types using the following loop:
INamespaceSymbol rootNs = assemblySymbol.GlobalNamespace;
var stack = new Stack<INamespaceSymbol>();
stack.Push(rootNs);
while (stack.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var member in stack.Pop().GetMembers())
    {
        if (member is INamespaceSymbol namespaceSymbol)
        {
            stack.Push(namespaceSymbol);
        }
        else if (member is INamedTypeSymbol namedTypeSymbol)
        {
            CheckIfItsAuditableEntityAndProcess...(context, namedTypeSymbol);
        }
    }
}


Thanks to you, I've solved the issue and generated my endpoints.

Thanks to the @Sinus32, I've managed to solve the problem with this answer
My source generator is looking like this now:
[Generator]
public class V1DeleteEndpointSourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    private const string AuditableEntityInterfaceName = "IAuditableEntity";

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        // No initialization required
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var compilation = context.Compilation;

        // Identify the module name from the application project name
        var moduleName = GetModuleName(context.Compilation.AssemblyName!);
        if (moduleName == null)
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(_moduleNameNotFoundDescriptor, Location.None));
            return;
        }

        // Construct the corresponding domain project name
        var domainProjectName = $"{moduleName}.Domain";
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(_domainProjectNameDescriptor, Location.None, domainProjectName));

        // Find the domain project in the referenced assemblies
        var domainAssemblySymbol = compilation
            .SourceModule
            .ReferencedAssemblySymbols
            .SingleOrDefault(assembly => string.Equals(assembly.Name, domainProjectName, StringComparison.Ordinal));

        if (domainAssemblySymbol == null)
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(_domainProjectNotFoundDescriptor, Location.None, domainProjectName));
            return;
        }

        var rootNs = domainAssemblySymbol.GlobalNamespace;
        var stack = new Stack<INamespaceSymbol>();
        stack.Push(rootNs);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var member in stack.Pop().GetMembers())
            {
                if (member is INamespaceSymbol namespaceSymbol)
                {
                    stack.Push(namespaceSymbol);
                }
                else if (member is INamedTypeSymbol namedTypeSymbol)
                {
                    if (!ImplementsIAuditableEntity(namedTypeSymbol))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var namespaceName = namedTypeSymbol.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString();
                    var className = namedTypeSymbol.Name;

                    var source = GenerateDeleteEndpointCode(namespaceName, moduleName, className);
                    context.AddSource($"{className}_DeleteEndpoint.g.cs", SourceText.From(source, Encoding.UTF8));
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(_endpointGeneratedDescriptor, Location.None, className));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool ImplementsIAuditableEntity(INamedTypeSymbol namedTypeSymbol)
        => namedTypeSymbol
            .AllInterfaces
            .Any(i => i.Name.Contains(AuditableEntityInterfaceName));

    private static string GetModuleName(string assemblyName)
    {
        // Assuming the assembly name follows the pattern {ModuleName}.Application
        var parts = assemblyName.Split('.');
        if (parts.Length > 1 && parts[1] == "Application")
        {
            return parts[0];
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid assembly name");
    }

    private static string GenerateDeleteEndpointCode(string namespaceName, string moduleName, string className)
    {
        var pluralClassName = Pluralize(className);
        return $@"
// WARNING: Auto-Generated by Source Generator.

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Common.Domain.StronglyTypedIds;
using Common.Domain.ResultMonad;
using Common.Application.Auth;
using Common.Application.Extensions;
using Common.Application.Persistence;
using {namespaceName};
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Common.Application.ModelBinders;
using Ardalis.Specification;

namespace {moduleName}.Application.{pluralClassName}.v1.Delete;

internal static class Endpoint
{{
    internal static void MapEndpoint(RouteGroupBuilder apiGroup)
    {{
        apiGroup
            .MapDelete(""{{id}}"", Delete{className}Async)
            .WithDescription(""Delete a {className}."")
            .MustHavePermission(CustomActions.Delete, CustomResources.{pluralClassName})
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)
            .TransformResultToNoContentResponse();
    }}

    private sealed class {className}ByIdSpec : SingleResultSpecification<{className}>
    {{
        public {className}ByIdSpec({className}Id id)
            => Query
                .Where(p => p.Id == id);
    }}

    private static async Task<Result> Delete{className}Async(
        [FromRoute, ModelBinder(typeof(StronglyTypedIdBinder<{className}Id>))] {className}Id id,
        [FromServices] IRepository<{className}> repository,
        [FromKeyedServices(nameof({moduleName}))] IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await repository
            .SingleOrDefaultAsResultAsync(new {className}ByIdSpec(id), cancellationToken)
            .TapAsync(entity => repository.Delete(entity))
            .TapAsync(async _ => await unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken));
}}
";
    }

    private static string Pluralize(string word)
    {
        if (word.EndsWith("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return $"{word.Substring(0, word.Length - 1)}ies";
        }

        if (word.EndsWith("s", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return $"{word}es";
        }

        return $"{word}s";
    }

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor _moduleNameNotFoundDescriptor = new(
        id: "SOURCEGEN001",
        title: "Module Name Not Found",
        messageFormat: "Module name not found",
        category: "SourceGenerator",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor _domainProjectNotFoundDescriptor = new(
        id: "SOURCEGEN002",
        title: "Domain Project Not Found",
        messageFormat: "Domain project {0} not found",
        category: "SourceGenerator",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor _endpointGeneratedDescriptor = new(
        id: "SOURCEGEN003",
        title: "Endpoint Generated",
        messageFormat: "Generated delete endpoint for {0}",
        category: "SourceGenerator",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Info,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor _domainProjectNameDescriptor = new(
        id: "SOURCEGEN004",
        title: "Domain Project Name",
        messageFormat: "Domain project name was {0}",
        category: "SourceGenerator",
        defaultSeverity: DiagnosticSeverity.Info,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);
}



As a side note, you should change this to an incremental source generator ASAP. You're killing Visual Studio performance, and it only gets exponentially worse as your code base increases.

@Blindy wow, thanks for the information. I don't have much knowledge about source generators yet. I'll definitely search about it.
